# Unable to keep the same size for background image also for navigation bullets in slideshow using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add background image for navigation bullets when it is active but full icon image not appearing like already existing image using .active in css block code. I have added my code below used in css.

css

```css
    <html>
     .dotOne {
       cursor: pointer;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       padding: 8px 52px 20px;
       margin: 0 50px;
       background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/HellBlade_2.png"     style="width:100%");
       border-radius: 100%;
       display: inline-block;
       transition:background-color :#1D93ED; 
     }

     .dotOne:active {
       cursor: pointer;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       padding: 8px 52px 20px;
       margin: 0 50px;
       background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/HellBlade_5.png"          style="width:100%");
       border-radius: 100%;
       display: inline-block;
       transition:background-color :#1D93ED; 
     }
     </html>
```

Comment: Is the CSS inside a `<html>` tag on your actual website? Also, you have parts of an HTML style attribute in the value of the `background-image` property.

Comment: I do not have any image value but i have used to call slide show let me add div section

Comment: <div style="text-align:center">
 <span class="dots dotOne" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dots dotTwo" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dots dotThree" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <span class="dots dotFour" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  </div>

Comment: I am using  background-size:110% 112%;
    background-position: cover; to customize now but not able to make same size as like normal image size which is specifies already